# Symfony 3 ralation OneToMany with joint table error on genarate:enities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, symfony

I have the following code (for 2 tables' Advert & City):
when I run cmd  'php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle' to generate setters and geters (Symfony3)
this error appear:

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@JoinColumn" in property
>   Ligo\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert::$cities was never imported. Did you
>   maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? 500
>   Internal Server Error - AnnotationException

```
<?php

namespace Ligo\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Advert
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="advert")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ligo\PlatformBundle\Repository\AdvertRepository")
 */
class Advert
{
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="City")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="adverts_cities",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="advert_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     */
    private $cities;
```

Comment: Which error ? You dont put it in your post...

Comment: hey @Letsrocks

[Semantical Error] The annotation "@JoinColumn" in property Ligo\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert::$cities was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? 500 Internal Server Error - AnnotationException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prefix JoinColumn annotation with ORM (`@ORM\JoinColumn`) since you did not specifically import it.

Comment: thank you I solved the problem with @ORM in all annotation.

Comment: class Advert
{
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="City")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="adverts_cities",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="advert_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     */
    private $cities;